# Proxy server vite : Window.env.API_URl doesn't work in vite config ts (is not defined)

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, global-variables, vuejs3, vite

I try to use my window env which is a global typescript object it works on all the project except for the quick config ts when I try to configure the API address with it it doesn't work (undefine window) while it works in all the other files.

In my router (that works):

> console.log(window.env.API_URL);

[image]

In my vite.config.ts(doesn't work):

[image]

if anyone can help me please thanks ;)

Comment: Finally I configure my window.env.API_URL in axios options before sending a request and it works.